# How do I take this integral?

Tags: integration

How do I take the integral of the Jacobian and show this equality?
I'm thinking of doing it component wise, but I feel that I'm overlooking something simpler.

[image]

Comment: What is the antiderivative of $J_f(y+t(x-y))(x-y)$ as a function of $t$? (Hint: $x$ and $y$ may be vectors, but they are still constants)

Comment: I'm not sure what function would have the Jacobian as the derivative. The (x-y) seems to come out through the chain rule.

Comment: What's the definition of the Jacobian??

Comment: The Jacobian is a matrix of the first order partial derivatives. I'm not sure how to take an integral of the matrix.

Comment: The Jacobian is the derivative! Of the function. It's the higher dimensional generalization of $f'$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$. Then by chain rule we have that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr(f(g(t))\Bigr) = J_f(g(t))\cdot g'(t)$$

because the Jacobian is the generalization of $f'$ or the total derivative, in a way that partial derivatives aren't. The crucial difference is that Jacobians will obey the fundamental theorem of calculus under the correct conditions, but arbitrary partials may not.

Comment: I thought the gradient was the generalization of f'. Thanks for clarifying this for me.

Comment: @Anonymous181 the gradient is a Jacobian. It is the special case for the codomain being $\mathbb{R}$